# Create a function to generate table from dataset

Tags: r, function

I have a dataset (lets call him `db_data`) and I would like to create a table from 2 variables of this dataset (lets call them `var1` and `var2`).

```
db_data <- base::data.frame(var1 = c("M", "M", "F", "F", "F"), 
                            var2 = c("brown", "blue", "brown", "brown", "brown"))
```

I can do it pretty easily like this :

```
tab <- base::table(db_data[j = c("var1", "var2")])
tab
```

My problem is that I would like to use it in a bigger work, many times. So I tried to create a function to do that, but there is no result at all.

```
# Create function
tab_function = function(data,
                         var1,
                         var2) {
tab <- base::table(data[j = c(var1, var2)])
tab
}

# Test
tab_function(data = db_data, var1 = "var1", var2 = "var2")
```

This is playing without error but I get a totally different result and no object from it. I tried using `get()`, `noquote()` and also

```
# This
tab_function(data = data, var1 = var1, var2 = var2)

# This
tab_function = function(data,
                         var1,
                         var2) {
tab <- base::table(data[j = c("var1", "var2")])
tab
}
```

I don't get it. It seems easy but it is not working.

Comment: (1) I get identical results between `table(.)` and `tab_function(.)`. (2) Both emit a warning discouraging the use of named arguments in `[` (other than `drop=`). Are you getting those warnings? If so, I recommend against ignoring them.

Comment: Removing `j = ` prevents the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return` to return something from a function. Also, I avoid the warning r2evans mentioned by changing the selection method of the two columns from your data.frame.

```
tab_function <- function(db_data, var1, var2){
  tab <- base::table(db_data[,names(db_data) %in% c(var1, var2)])
  return(tab)
}

tab_function(db_data, "var1", "var2")

    var2
var1 blue brown
   F    0     3
   M    1     1
```

Comment: Though it’s good practice, you don’t have to use return. R will return the last output of their function automatically. In this regard the OPs code is fine (it would return tab); they do not need to use the return explicitly.